# Jenkins: Is there a Folder/View level security plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a plugin that allows for a View level security. For example I had an AD group I wish to assign to have modification/Execute permissions to ALL jobs under a specific View.

I understand that Views are just filters on the main page of Jenkins but with the quantity of plugins out there I needed to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Role Strategy Plugin worked wonders for my organization.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/

You cannot control access at view levels but, you can play around with folder plugin to get the desired level of access